# How do I set a background image for an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, background-image

I currently have this, but it is not setting the background as expected:

```
<body style: background-image url()>
```

Also I need it to be a file not a link

Comment: What did you try? You can do it the same way as standard HTML.

Comment: @dvo I used<body style: background-image url()>

Comment: Hi @AlexanderKlyachko - welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to let the SO community help you more easily, you should add some more detail to your question. As dvo mentioned, adding your current code to the question is a good first step. You can use codes formatting blocks to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like @Sverre beat me to the suggestion of moving your CSS style to a separate file. If you prefer to leave it directly in the tags, you will have to reformat it a bit like so:

```
<body style="background-image: url('https://yourdomain.com/some-image.png')">
```

Comment: I need a file to be the background not a link

Comment: Is this website going to be accessible over the Internet? If so, you will need some sort of web link in there rather than a file path. Another user's machine would not know what to do with 'C:\Users\you\Documents\some-image.png' as that file path only exists on your machine, but the CSS is rendered on the client's machine.

Comment: So instead, the image is usually hosted somewhere on the Internet (either along with your website or with a third-party service such as AWS S3/Cloudfront). If you place the image in a folder in your website (e.g., YourRootWebsiteFolder/images/some-image.png), you will be able to access it using either an absolute URL ('https://yourdomain.com/images/some-image.png') or a relative URL ('/images/some-image.png').

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: You are most welcome. If this answer or any other solved your question, it is good practice on SO to mark one as the accepted answer. You can also up-vote any answers that you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing this in your CSS file. [This page goes in depth on CSS backgrounds and shows you how to style them as well.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

You can do it in the body tag as follows:

`body {
  background-image: url("example.jpg");
}`